# Cannot set valuekey different than displaykey in typeahead js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I want to be able to display 2 fields from my JSON returned data in typeahead dropdown box, BUT use as value one of them.

As it is, the dropdown displays the two fields as i want and when i select one value the textbox has only one field as i want.

But as soon as i leave the textbox it gets populated with the dropdown value.

My HTML field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtlitm">Item Code:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlitm" name="txtlitm" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#txtlitm').typeahead(
{
    minLength: 4,
    highlight: true,
    hint: false
},
{
    displayKey: function(q) {
        return q.litm + " - " + q.dsc;
    },
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.getJSON('@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/home/GetItemCodes/")' + query, function (data) {
            process(data);
        });

    }
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, data) {
    $('#txtlitm').val(data.litm);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display`, e.g.

```
displayKey: 'name',
display: 'seq',
```

`valueKey` might be deprecated. I found another solution using `display` and it works with `jquery-1.12.4` and `typeahead 0.11.1`. I initialize 2 `bloodhounds`, but only wanted one datum to populate my input box. So the user can type in the ID, or the name, click the suggestion and then populate with ID regardless.